# Use of generalisation error in the process of NN training

Tags: neural-networks, cross-validation

Will I be breaking the logic of supervised training if I check generalisation error in the process of NN training to see if it increases, and then do something to the NN if it does? Generalisation error is the only indication of overfitting. On the other hand, using generalisation error for training purpose implicitely incorporates the generalisation set into the training set, although they have to remain independent and non-overlapping if bias is to be avoided. Would it be statistically correct to use generalisation error as described, and then use a separate validation set to check NN's true generalisation performance?

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29805/on-line-detection-of-over-fitting-in-neural-networks/34432#34432

Comment: @mbq, I take it three data sets are the way to go.

Comment: The standard way to do it is to divide your data into three sets : training set, validation set and test set. You train the chosen classifier on the training set, and check generalization error on the validation set, and you can react to certain values of it accordingly (changing some meta-parameters like regularization parameter). On the very end, you check the error of the classifier on the test set, and report it as the generalization error of the classifier. The general idea is to perform the final approximation of generalization error on the data, which the classifier never seen before.

Comment: @mbq IMO the way to go is not to use NN at all... See my answer on that linked question.

Comment: @mbq, Geoffrey Hinton would disagree ;)

Comment: There are NN enthusiasts out there... in the Google labs: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DleXA5ADG78

Comment: @anna-earwen Any ML algorithm, whether it is kNN, NB, SVM, RF or any NN flavour is simply some heuristical fitting of an overparametrised function to a training data; an ungrateful and dangerous task which is not well stated and very prone to overfitting. However, it is pretty easy technically -- we know optimization heuristics that work fast and effective. Thus, the real work in ML is robustizing and validating models, possibly analysing them to get some information about the modelled process (tbc)

Comment: @anna-earwen Now, NN science goes in an opposite direction -- to wrap the optimisation part in so many layers of complexity, buzzwords and suspicious biological analogies that everything is so bloated with parameters that proper validation is unenforceable and models look better than they actually are.
As a disclaimer, the above applies to modelling; NNs are great as a manipulable programming language and thus very useful in steering theory and surroundings.